# Set longtable to fit the page-width

Tags: tables, longtable, width, fit

I would like to set a longtable to fit correctly the page-witdh. From now, I've this situation:

[image: longtable-width-error]

and the related tex code is:

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[tableposition=below]{caption}
```

[...]

```
We now present a table that summarises the possible scenarios that can happen in the overlap zone.
{\small \begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}

\hline \textbf{Type of movement in the overlap zone} & \textbf{State of the object in camera 1} & \textbf{State of the object in camera 2}  \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\hline \textbf{Type of movement in the overlap zone} & \textbf{State of the object in camera 1} & \textbf{State of the object in camera 2}  \\ \hline
\endhead

\hline
\caption{Table title.}
\endfoot

\caption{Table title.}
\endlastfoot

Object moving from camera 1 to camera 2 & Object will eventually be in the \emph{exiting} state and the be \emph{deleted} & Object will be recognised as a \emph{new} object, then become \emph{to be classified} and eventually \emph{classified} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}  
\end{center}
}
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the `tabu` with its environment

```
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|X|X|X|}
…
\end{longtabu}
```

For more information, see the documentation of `tabu`.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works fine. Just another question: how can I set padding values for the cells?

Comment: I don't know, what you mean exactly by "padding values" (English is not my first language).

Comment: I mean the distance between the borders (top, right, bottom and left) and the text inside a cell.

Comment: The horizontal space can be controlled via options to the `X` columns or usually via `@{…}`. The vertical space can be controlled via `\tabulinesep` and `\extrarowsep` (see the documentation).

Comment: You need to `\usepackage{tabu}` and make sure that the column to be restricted is of the column type `X`.

Comment: I still not your solution, someone explain, please?

Answer (score 25):

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
```

the `center` environment has no affect on `longtable` as the table rows are always full width.

The `longtable` documentation does give an example of how to produce a full width table:

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|@{}}
```

...

Comment: Shouldn't that be as follows?
`\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}` `\setlength{\LTright}{0pt}`

Comment: @Urhixidur the braces are optional

Answer (score 5):

an ancient solution is possible with the package [ltablex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltablex):
Here is a MWE with `booktabs`, which provides better rules then `\hline` (I recommend to read at least chapter 2 from `texdoc booktabs`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
\textbf{Type of movement in the overlap zone} & \textbf{State of the object in camera 1} & \textbf{State of the object in camera 2}  \\ \toprule
\endhead
\caption{Table title.}
\endfoot
Object moving from camera 1 to camera 2 & Object will eventually be in the \emph{exiting} state and the be \emph{deleted} 
& 
Object will be recognised as a \emph{new} object, then become \emph{to be classified} and eventually \emph{classified}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]