# Making widths of tables equal to width of textblock

Tags: tables, longtable

[image]

I have various tables in my document, and all of them have different widths. Is there a way I can evenly space out all of them, and have all widths equal to the width of the textblock (=pagewidth minus widths of margins)?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\addtolength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%Tables preamble
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow} 

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
\newcommand\mceight[1]{\multicolumn{8}{l}{#1}}
\newcommand\mctwelve[1]{\multicolumn{12}{c}{#1}} 

\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\widowpenalty500
\clubpenalty500
\exhyphenpenalty=50 %for line-breaking at an explicit hyphen
\brokenpenalty=4991
\predisplaypenalty=10000
\postdisplaypenalty=1549
\displaywidowpenalty=1602
\floatingpenalty = 20000

% Header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 


\begin{document}

\subsection{Appendix of Tables}

\newgeometry{margin=0.5in} 

\begin{table*}[ht] \centering
\fontsize{10}{12}\helvet
\caption{Summary statistics 1}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{S[table-format=2.2]}} \toprule
& & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Quantiles} \\ \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{Minimum} & \textbf{25th percentile} & \textbf{Median} & \textbf{75th percentile} & \textbf{Maximum} \\ \midrule
\textbf{Panel A: Female labour force} \\ \midrule
\textbf{2004-05} \\ \hdashline
{Hourly wage}  & 17.17 & 0 & 3.75 & 5.48 & 12.5 & 250\ \\ \hdashline
{Age (in years)}& 9.98 & 15 & 22 & 29 & 38 & 60\ \\ \hdashline
{Years of experience} & 10.61 & 0 & 8 & 15 & 25 & 40\ \\ \hdashline
{Years of education} & 7.13 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 12 & 16\ \\ \hdashline
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\begin{longtable}{ l*{7}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
\fontsize{10}{12}\helvet
\caption{Summary statistics 2}
\label{tab:...} \\
\toprule
\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Dependent\\ Variables}}
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Share(\%)}}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Avg hourly wage}}
            & {\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Avg\\ differential}}}              \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled}
    & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled}                       \\
   \hdashline                                                               \\
\endfirsthead
%%%%
\caption{Summary statistics 2 (cont.)} \\ \toprule                                    
\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Dependent\\ Variables}}
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Share(\%)}}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Avg hourly wage}}
            & {\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Avg\\ differential}}} \\  
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}  
& \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled} & \textbf{Men} &  
\textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled} \\ \midrule \\ \endhead \midrule
\multicolumn{8}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot\endlastfoot
\mceight{\textbf{PANEL A: 2011-2012}} \\ \midrule
\\
\mceight{\textbf{Panel A.1: Sector (Urban or Rural)}} \\ \midrule
Rural  & 51.5 & 54 & 52 & 28.54 & 18.83 & 26.92 & 51.5 \\ \hdashline
Urban  & 48.4 & 46 & 48 & 45.19 & 41.86 & 45    & 7.8 \\ \hdashline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For simple tables check here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-force-a-table-into-page-width ... For longtable check here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110266/set-longtable-to-fit-the-page-width ... Off topic try to use caption only above or only below your tables. Your question is a duplicate of the first or second link. I would say with the first since you just added langtable as a tag and don't asking anything about this

Comment: What's the reason for setting the value of `\clubpenalty` twice?

Comment: @Mico sorry about that, did not notice the repetition. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first table, I suggest you use a `tabular*` environment, with width set to `\textwidth`, inside a `table` environment (*not* a `table*` environment). For the `longtable`, I suggest you use an `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive in the argument of the environment.

I would also strive for a less-cluttered look in the tables, say, by omitting as many horizontal lines as possible.

I have no idea how you defined the instruction `\helvet`. I've assumed you want it to mean, "switch to Helvetica for the table material". To do so, I've loaded the `helvet` package and I've replaced both instances of `\helvet` with `\sffamily`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\addtolength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx,helvet}

%Tables preamble
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow} 

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
\newcommand\mceight[1]{\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{#1}}
\newcommand\mctwelve[1]{\multicolumn{12}{@{}c}{#1}} 

\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\widowpenalty500
\clubpenalty500
\clubpenalty=9996
\exhyphenpenalty=50 %for line-breaking at an explicit hyphen
\brokenpenalty=4991
\predisplaypenalty=10000
\postdisplaypenalty=1549
\displaywidowpenalty=1602
\floatingpenalty = 20000

% Header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 


\begin{document}

\subsection{Appendix of Tables}

%\newgeometry{margin=0.5in} 

\begin{table}[ht] 
\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
\sffamily
\sisetup{detect-all}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{Summary statistics 1}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    l S[table-format=2.2]     S[table-format=2.0]
    *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]} S[table-format=3.0]} 
\toprule
& & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Quantiles} \\ 
\cmidrule{4-6}
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{Min.} & 
\textbf{25th percentile} & \textbf{Median} & 
\textbf{75th percentile} & \textbf{Max.} \\ 
\midrule
\textbf{Panel A: Female labour force} \\ 
\midrule
\textbf{2004--05} \\ %\hdashline
Hourly wage    & 17.17 & 0 & 3.75 & 5.48 & 12.5 & 250\\ %\hdashline
Age (in years) & 9.98 & 15 & 22 & 29 & 38 & 60\\ %\hdashline
Years of experience & 10.61 & 0 & 8 & 15 & 25 & 40\\ %\hdashline
Years of education & 7.13 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 12 & 16\\ %\hdashline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\begingroup  % localize to 'longtable' env.
\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
\sffamily
\sisetup{detect-all}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
    \caption{Summary statistics 2} \label{tab:...} \\
    \toprule
      \multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Dependent\\ Variables}}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Share (\%)}}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Avg hourly wage}}
    & {\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Avg\\ differential}}}  \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule{5-7}
    & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled}
    & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled}   \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
%%%%
    \caption{Summary statistics 2 (cont.)} \\ 
    \toprule                                    
      \multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Dependent\\ Variables}}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Share (\%)}}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Avg hourly wage}}
    & {\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Avg\\ differential}}} \\  
    \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7}  
    & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled} & \textbf{Men} 
    & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled} \\ 
    \midrule  
    \endhead 

    \midrule
    \multicolumn{8}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
    \endfoot

    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

\mceight{\textbf{PANEL A: 2011--2012}} \\ 
\addlinespace
\mceight{\textbf{Panel A.1: Sector (Urban or Rural)}} \\ \addlinespace
Rural  & 51.5 & 54 & 52 & 28.54 & 18.83 & 26.92 & 51.5 \\ %\hdashline
Urban  & 48.4 & 46 & 48 & 45.19 & 41.86 & 45    & 7.8 \\ %\hdashline

\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. The helvet and changing font size wasn't doing any good, so shifted to using `\footnotesize`

Comment: Also, the caption for the first table comes at the bottom every time. Something evidently wrong in what I am doing?

Comment: @KushaVerma - If the first table's caption is being placed below rather than above the tabular material in your document, it's probably because the `\caption` instruction occurs after, rather than before, the `tabular` (or `tabular*`) environment. (Observe the position of the caption in the screenshot above.)

Comment: @KushaVerma - The reason `\fontsize{10}{12}` wasn't working for you is that you failed to provide the instruction `\selectfont`. See my code for how to use `\fontsize` correctly.

Comment: Even when I do as you suggested, I get the caption at the bottom of the table`\begin{table}[ht] 
\caption{Summary statistics 1}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    l S[table-format=2.2]     S[table-format=2.0]
    *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]} S[table-format=3.0]} 
\toprule`

Comment: Also, this method doesn't seem to work in the landscape environment. Are there any modifications I should be making for landscape?

Comment: @KushaVerma - Your latest code snippet doesn't compile, so I can't tell what you're doing. (Are you maybe loading a package that affects where the caption is placed?) For tables in landscape orientation, I suggest you load the `rotating` package and use a `sidewaystable` environment instead of the basic `table` environment.

Comment: you were right, the problem with the caption was due to an additional package I was using, got that sorted. However, for the landscape I don't want my tables to be in a `sidewaystable` environment, and would prefer to keep using the basic `table` environment.

Comment: @KushaVerma - I'm afraid I honestly don't understand your document setup well enough to 'get' why you would *not* want to use a `sidewaystable` environment. You may want to post a new query, in which you explain in more detail what's going on in the document's preamble, and ask for alternatives to `sidewaystable`. The best solution will likely depend on pieces of information that haven't been shared so far.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll post a different question for that. Thanks for your help!