# How to use multicolumn with a decimal number?

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

I want to draw the table below in latex using the `tabularx` environment. However, the \multicolumn{1.5} is unfortunately not working.
Do you have any idea how to draw this kind of tables where the multicolumn command uses a decimal number (to preserve the same cell width)?

[image]

I drew a table using the below code, but the cells don't have the same width.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx} {0.3\textwidth}
    { l  l  l l}
    \toprule[2pt]
    Parameter & \multicolumn{3}{c}{value} \\
    \midrule[0.5pt]
    P1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{V2}\\
    P2 & V1 & V2 & V3 \\        
    \bottomrule[2pt]
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Result:

[image]

Kind regards. Widad.

Comment: Why are you using `tabularx` but not the `X` columntype? Also don't post such fragments only.

Comment: Yes I was using the X columntype. I changed it to test if it's the problem root cause.

Comment: The environment's assigned width -- `0.3\textwidth` -- simply isn't sufficient. Try, say, `0.5\textwidth`, and do revert to using `X` column types.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to specify a multicolumn of 1.5 cells, you can multiply the widths until you reach an integer - multiply by 2 to get 3 in this case. The other rows need to be multiplied as well.

Now, the next problem is that no cells of width 1 remain to compute the size  of the multicolumns. You can insert a phantom row in a `longtable` to obtain the right sizes and `\kill` it afterwards. A bit over`kill` - but nobody said LaTeX code was pretty :D

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|llllll|}
\hline
 & V1 & V2 & V3 & V4 & V5 & V6\kill 
Parameter & \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{value}\\
\hline
P1 & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{V1} & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{V2}\\
\hline
P2 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{V1} & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{V2} & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{V3}\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Marijn, this is exactly what I was looking for. It's a smart and easy solution, thank you!

Comment: I used Marjin's solution, but the longtable exceeds my textwidth. Is there any solution to force its width to textwidth?

Comment: From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110274) from the author of `longtable`: put `\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}` before the table.

Comment: Yes I already tried it, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I that case you could post a new question with an example that shows the textwidth problem (it might be closed as a duplicate but you can try it anyway if you believe that your problem is different).

Comment: @WidadES-SOUFI a table is as wide as the data you put in it, so without seeing your data impossible to say.  However you can put `\small` or `\footnotesize` before the longtable so it will be smaller and might fit (depending how much too wide it is of course)