# `longtable` with `tabularx` to wrap long cells using `X` type column

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, tabu

What is the best way to use `tabularx` `X` column type in `longtable`? I read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110266/set-longtable-to-fit-the-page-width) that [ltablex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltablex) is "ancient" and the same post also mentions `tabu` but its [page](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf) mentions that the package might not be properly maintained. So I wonder, which is a preferred way? (also i would like to avoid manually working with multi-columns)

Comment: personally I'd avoid X in most cases (despite having written that code:-) but maybe try the `xltabular` package

Comment: also ltablex code is old (from last century sometime) but it is newer than longtable and tabularx, so age isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe I should be more specific since there might be a better way. I am looking for a simple way to auto-wrap cells that are too long so that I can avoid using `p{xcm}` since the table is being used in different documents with different margins and wrong size will make the cells unnecessarily short (or too long).

Comment: it depends but usually something like `{llp{.4\textwidth}` avoids the overhead of `tabularx` and still adapts to the document page size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package. You can use `X` columns in `longtblr` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=10mm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\begin{document}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
  \SetTblrStyle{firsthead}{font=\bfseries}
  \SetTblrStyle{firstfoot}{fg=blue}
  \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{red}
}
\begin{longtblr}[
  theme = fancy,
  caption = {Long Tabular},
  entry = {Short Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
  note{a} = {It is the first footnote.},
  note{$\dag$} = {It is the second long long long long long long footnote.},
]{
  colspec = {XXX}, hlines,
  rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1,
  row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {teal9},
  row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7},
}
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta\TblrNote{a}       & Eta    \\
 Iota    & Kappa\TblrNote{$\dag$} & Lambda \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Foot    & Foot  & Foot    \\
\end{longtblr}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.

\end{document}
```

[image]