# How to create a longtable with specific width and adaptive column widths in it?

Tags: longtable, column-width

I need to create a longtable with fixed average width that contains one adaptive column and two others with derived widths to fit the average table width.

I tried this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110266/set-longtable-to-fit-the-page-width) but I need a parbox in last column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}


Perfect Fit

\begin{longtable}[l]{|p{0.35\textwidth}|p{0.05\textwidth}|p{0.6\textwidth}|}%   

    HTML & - & HyperText Markup Language \\
    PHP & - & Hypertext Preprocessor \\
    Oceanogr. Oceanogr. .& - &          oceanography, oceanographic(al) oceanography, oceanographic(al) oceanography, oceanographic(al)

\end{longtable}

Manual Adjustment 1

\begin{longtable}[l]{|l|p{0.05\textwidth}|p{0.26\textwidth}|}%  

HTML & - & HyperText Markup Language \\
PHP & - & Hypertext Preprocessor \\
Oceanogr. Oceanogr. Oceanogr. Oceanogr. Oceanogr.& - &          oceanography, oceanographic(al) oceanography, oceanographic(al) oceanography, oceanographic(al)

\end{longtable}


Manual Adjustment 2

\begin{longtable}[l]{|l|p{0.05\textwidth}|p{0.54\textwidth}|}%  

    HTML & - & HyperText Markup Language \\
    PHP & - & Hypertext Preprocessor \\
    Oceanogr. Oceanogr. Oceanogr. & - &         oceanography, oceanographic(al) oceanography, oceanographic(al) oceanography, oceanographic(al)

\end{longtable}     

\end{document}
```

Can I just get the resulted first column width someway and substract it from textwidth to set widths for other columns?

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the `xltabular` package. It combines the features of `longtable`(mid-table pabe breaks)  with `tabularx` (flexible width `X` type columns).

Comment: By the way, although the numbers of your `p` type columns in your first table add up to `1\textwidth`, the table is still too wide. To make it exactly as wide as the textwidth, you would have to take the value of `\tsbcolsep` (2 per column) and the width of the vertical lines (`\arrayrulewidth)  into account.

Comment: Answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539658/how-to-use-xltabular-environment-in-glossaries-package/539737#539737