# Set last column of longtable to pagewidth

Tags: longtable

I am having an issue with a longtable I wish to include in my PhD document. It seems to be a common problem ([for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110266/set-longtable-to-fit-the-page-width)) but I am new to Latex and the solutions I have found have not work for me. The issue is quite simple, the longtable does not fit the width of the page and the column. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}
\setlength\LTleft{\fill}
\setlength\LTright{\fill}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll@{}}\toprule
\textbf{Date} & \textbf{Example - Example and Example} & \textbf{Example - Example and Example} \\* \midrule
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
\endfoot
%
\endlastfoot
%
1460 & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. &  \\
1470 & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. &  \\
1470-1535 &  & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. \\
1532 & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. &  \\
1535-36 &  & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. \\
1537 & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. &  \\
1538 & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. &  \\
1541 &  & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. \\

[...]

2021 &  & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. \\* \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The current example code will most likely not result in a table that is wider than the textwidth. Please prepare an example that allows others to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You may be interested in the xltabular package and its X type column.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I just modified the code to show better the issue. I tried with the xltabular package but I didn't manage to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried again with xltabular and it is perfectly working now. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP claims that  it solve himself by use of comment.

Answer (score 4):

Text in cells of the second and third column is longer than text width, therefore, the cells in these columns must allow the text to be broken into multiple lines. Such fetures has `p{width}` column type, however, simpler is to use `X` column type defined in `xltabular` (which combine `tabularx` and `longtable`, `longtblr` defined in the `tabularray` package etc.

With `longtblr` MWE with your table can be as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
\SetTblrStyle{head}{font=\small}
\SetTblrStyle{foot}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
                    }

    \begin{longtblr}[
  theme = fancy,
caption = {Long table \texttt{longtblr}},
  label = {tab:longtblr}]{
    rowhead = 1,
    colspec = {@{} l X[j]    X[j] @{}},
     row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
                        }
    \toprule
Date        & Example - Example and Example 
                & Example - Example and Example \\* 
    \midrule
% table body
1460        & \lipsum[1]
                &  \\
1461        &   &   \lipsum[2]  \\
1470        & \lipsum[3].
                &  \\
1470-1535   &   & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. \\
1532        & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text.
                &  \\
1535-36     &   & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. \\
1537        & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text.
                &  \\
1538        & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text.
                &  \\
1541        &  & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. \\

[...]       &   &   \\

2021        &  & Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text. \\* 
            \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I finally managed to solve the problem with the X type column by using the xltabular package.